# Cannot retrieve hostname calling my TCPListener Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, tcplistener

I am writing a simple FTP service using TcpListener and would like to find out what hostname (domain with multiple subdomains) the incoming call is using.

Is this possible?

```
//Barebone TCPListener example
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener listener;
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 21)

listener.Start();

TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

//Great, incoming... what domain are they using to call my service?

//This only gives me the local and remote IP..
//IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.LocalEndPoint;
//IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think TCP fundamentally *has* that information. That's why HTTP has the "Host" header so clients can specify it.

Essentially, making a TCP connection to a host name is equivalent to resolving the host name into an address, then making the connection as if there'd never *been* a name.

Comment: So the information about the hostname is lost somewhere on the way?

Comment: @ThomasC: It's lost in that step 1 is "resolve host name to address" and step 2 is "connect to address". So at the *TCP* level the information is gone. I believe some FTP servers support a non-standard "Host" header, so you could do that *within your server code* but it's not part of `TcpClient`. It's in the higher level protocol.

Comment: Would the solution be to use Socket instead of TCP?

Comment: @ThomasC: No - it's still TCP, fundamentally. The real solution would be to use different IP addresses for different hosts...

Comment: ok, thanks. A bit wiser now, I wont try to find what is not there.   Still wonder though, how it can be done :)

Comment: @ThomasC: Fundamentally, it can't. Suppose you're living in a house with several people, and you're all listed in the telephone directory. I look up the number of one of those people, then dial your phone number. Unless I then ask for the person, how would you expect to know who I looked up? It's fundamentally the same sequence of operations here.