# Get my own hostname in .net FTP Server implementation

Tags: .net, ftp, dns, tcpclient, malware-detection

I am developing an app for malware analysis. It tracks all ftp request of a virus. So i am implementing my own ftp server and i have a dns server in my own pc redirecting all hosts to 127.0.0.1.
The problem is that i want to know the host name of the ftp request. It can be any adrress because the dns server return 127.0.0.1.
I am using .net and TcpClient. 
I resolve local and remote ip (127.0.0.1) but i dont know how to get the host name accessed by the malware.
In http protocol the host name travels in the header, but i dont know how to get it in ftp protocol

Comment: Not exactly what you want but perhaps might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716748/reverse-ip-domain-check

Comment: Just to be clear... you have your own FTP server, and you want to trap the requested hostname of a caller within .net? Is your FTP server within IIS?

Comment: @HBomb I made my own ftp server, and I made also my own DNS server, so I can control everything, the problem is that in dns server, i dont know wich protocol is requesting a name (ftp o http etc) and in ftp server i dont know the host requested

Comment: What is your specific DNS server implementation? You will have to intercept the original host name before the reroute occurs, because its lost after that. I believe it is removed from the ethernet frame as well on reroute.

Answer (score 0):

FTP doesn't contain this information, nor does TCP which it is built on. HTTP specifically has this and other information we're used to with web development in the header portion of the packets. You have to collect this information at or prior to DNS resolution.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706928

---

Also, you would need TcpListener not TcpClient to listen for FTP requests.

Comment: Can I know in the dns server wich protocol is requesting an Ip, so I can catch the host name?

Comment: Information outside of the domain is not passed during DNS resolution, here's a trace example - http://serverfault.com/a/173193

Comment: I would suggest looking at FiddlerCore. I've only ever used Fiddler for intercepting HTTP, but I know it can be configured for FTP interception as well. FiddlerCore is its functionality as a .NET library. It operates as a proxy intercepting all traffic through WinINET. http://fiddler.wikidot.com/misc-information-page#toc1

Answer (score 0):

While vee_ess is correct that neither FTP nor TCP contains this information, if the connection is occuring over the internet then the connection is technically TCP/IP... and the IP protocol does contain this information within the Ethernet frame.

What you have to do is read this information from the raw ethernet frame (and as vee_ess mentions, prior to DNS resolution).

Since this is tagged in .Net, I'm going to assume you want to stay in .Net. So I would recommend **pCapDotNet.**

http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/

This is a .Net wrapper for the  winpcap tool, which will allow you to filter, intercept and read link layer packets. See the documentation here:

https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html

It operates at the *network device layer.* This means that it will intercept packets essentially at the network adapter, which should be prior to your DNS server reading and rewriting the packet. You should then store the pair of the original sending IP, and the requested hostname from within the ethernet frame. Your DNS server will send back down the resolved IP address to the caller, and the caller will contact your FTP server directly via its IP.

At that point, you can compare the senders IP address to whatever was stored, and you now know what the original hostname requested was.

Comment: I tried this option. but the problem is that the computer is offline, without an ethernet cable for security reasons (malware analisys) and I dont know why the packages dont go out to the ethernet card, so i cant track them. Maybe it is because the address is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: How can your DNS sever not have network connectivity? Are you saying your DNS and FTP implementations are on the exact same box?

Comment: My Dns server and my ftp server are both in the same computer, so, when a virus try to access any ftp address by it host name, the dns server response is 127.0.0.1 and the virus access to the local ftp server

Comment: You cannot intercept the packet then, as it never leaves your network card. My advice is to have 3 boxes. 1 is the virus source, the second is the DNS, and the 3rd is your ftp. Then you connect them all via ethernet (but dont connect anything else, to keep the virus contained). You can then intercept the packets and get the host name as described above.